# Could not locate nacl lib, searched for libsodium

Tags: python, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I am trying to create project using python, flask and pycharm. While I was deploying the code using "flask deploy" command, I got "OSError: Could not locate nacl lib, searched for libsodium" issue. I could not solve the issue since I am new to python, flask and pycharm.
Need help.

Comment: where do you try to use `flask deploy`? Maybe you should find page with `sodium` or `nacl`, download it and install it. It can be program created with C/C++ (or other language) and you have to install it separatelly (not with `pip`).

Comment: libsodium: [GitHub](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) and documentation for [installing](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation)

Comment: I cloned the repository and did as instructed in the installation document. But getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-nacl
```